# how to remove specific text from textbox while keeping the remaining text intact

Tags: jquery, asp.net, textbox, replace

im trying to replace text in a text on blur so if the user enters this:

```
Hello/test
```

i want it to be replaced by:

```
test
```

im using a basic textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fullName" CssClass="textBoxes"></asp:TextBox>
```

with asp.net 4.0 and jquery.

how can i do that?

thanks.

Comment: Are you after replacing whatever the user has entered with "test", or removing anything they enter before (and including) the `/` and keeping the text that follows the `/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the functionality you want it to only keep the value of the string after the `/`, not just to simply replace the 'Hello/', try this:

```
$(".textBoxes").blur(function() {
    var values = $(this).val().split('/');
    $(this).val(values[values.length-1])
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/26tnX/)

Comment: This is a good answer but #fullName won't work because that's not the client ID.  You'll have to emit the script on the server to populate the client id or emit a variable etc... or put an Eval statement in the aspx.

Comment: @swannee You're right - forgot about that as I've been spoiled by MVC not butchering UI code. I've amended the selector - although I guess the OP will have a method of selecting exactly which fields should have this functionality.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - thank you, works great as for the id it will work if the page clientidmode is static.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegExp to replace the unwanted string(s) with a blank string:

```
$('textarea, input[type="text"]').on('blur', function () {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/(hello\/)/gi, '');
});
```

This regular expression looks for any instance of `hello/` (case-insensitive) and replaces it with a empty string.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/K8xMf/